# How to use geo-location in a xamarin forms web view page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing a app that needs to open the mobile forcast.io website I am using xamarin forms to do this. it loads the mobile website just fine but it does not pull up the current location! now if I go to the site in chrome browser for android it works just fine here is my code:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App.Radar
{
    public partial class RadarHome : ContentPage
    {
        public RadarHome()
        {
            var browser = new WebView();
            {
                browser.Source = "https://forecast.io";

                Content = browser;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

and here is what my output log says:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Use of the Application Cache is deprecated on insecure origins. Support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See google url  for more details.", source:  (0)
08-09 09:12:25.332 I/chromium( 5979): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Use of the Application Cache is deprecated on insecure origins. Support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See google url for more details.", source:  (0)
[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See google url for more details.", source: http://forecast.io/js/mobile.min.js?rel=1454000774782 (1)
08-09 09:12:33.522 I/chromium( 5979): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See google url for more details.", source: http://forecast.io/js/mobile.min.js?rel=1454000774782 (1)
08-09 09:12:34.002 W/cr_BindingManager( 5979): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 5979
08-09 09:12:46.452 D/Mono    ( 5979): [0xd89ff930] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
08-09 09:12:48.452 D/ViewRootImpl( 5979): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
08-09 09:12:48.532 D/ViewRootImpl( 5979): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
```

I'm testing this on a Samsung galaxy s7 running api 23.

Why isn't it getting my current location?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I'm proving your app, and I don't have this problem with the GPS.

[image: example]

You are working in a with a real phone, when you debug in your

Deployed AndroidManifest.xml need to add android permissions to the application can use the gps.

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/general/projects/add_permissions_to_android_manifest/

rigth click in the android project -> android manifest and activate in the list 
the permissions necessary to work with the gps

[image: Android Manifest]

INTERNET – for accessing network resources.

ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION – for location services.

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

search the option of location and wath is enable

[image: menu]

### [image: location]

I probe the app in my table and the location that the application take is the location relative of the my public ip. And I thinking because this a external web page, the took the location of my provider of internet .

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I have an idea try this

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8c19e8/xamarin-android-working-with-gps-and-locations/

create a method that save the Latitude and Longitude of the phone.

```
    public double Latitude { get; set; }  
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
```

and when you save this parameters  y the Api of forecast

https://developer.forecast.io/docs/v2

There are two types of API calls. A forecast request returns the current forecast (for the next week):

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
A time-machine request returns the observed weather at a given time (for many places, up to 60 years in the past):

https://api.forecast.io/forecast/APIKEY/LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,TIME

**replaces the default link for this with the parameter and you have the current weather **

Regards. I hope you have a nice day. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply the reason your not seeing is because its on wifi it works on wifi but not on cellular data any other suggestions why?

Comment: Like I say in the second part. activate the permissions in the android  manifest. Compile again and run the application in your phone.

Other options you can check the developer options in the phone, 
http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/google-android/34-useful-things-you-can-do-in-android-developer-options-new-3590299/

Comment: all the proper permissions are in the android manifest any other ideas?

Comment: Try with other phone android if you have it. I can try in 3 o 4 hours with my phone to rule out is a specific configuration of the phone. Let me try in a table that I have in my job. Give me 5min to try.

Comment: I update the answer. Let me know if you resolved the problem.

Comment: Marcos José Pérez Pérez Thanks for the suggestion! The only issue is that this is using xamrian android I am using xamrian forms any other suggestions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is the same. Work for both.